# What is "let rec (-) x y = y - x in 1 - 2 - 3" doing?

Tags: ocaml

I saw `let (-) x y = y - x in 1 - 2 - 3` and `let rec (-) x y = y - x in 1 - 2 - 3` these two examples in a book about ocaml. When I saw the former one, I thought I understood the trick behind until I saw the latter function. It seems that the latter function is having some stack overflow problem, but why is it the case?  How does ocaml evaluate these two expressions separately?

Comment: Note the `rec` keyword in the second example and the absence of it in the first. I'm sure your book explains what that means, and what shadowing is. With that understanding you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be helpful to rename the `let` bound functions.

```ml
let (-) x y = y - x
in 1 - 2 - 3

(* The above expression is equivalent to the following. *)

let f x y = y - x
in f (f 1 2) 3

(* Which reduces to the following. *)

let f x y = y - x
in 3 - (2 - 1)
```

Note that the function we defined, `let (-) x y`, is different from the function which we use in the definition, `y - x`. This is because `let` without `rec` doesn't bind the function name within the definition. Hence, the `(-)` operator in the definition is the native minus operator. Therefore, the result is `2`.

Now, consider the second example.

```ml
let rec (-) x y = y - x
in 1 - 2 - 3

(* The above expression is equivalent to the following. *)

let rec f x y = f y x
in f (f 1 2) 3
```

Now, what does `f 1 2` reduce to? It reduces to `f 2 1`, which reduces to `f 1 2`, which reduces to `f 2 1`, and so on ad infinitum. Now, in a language without tail call optimization this would result in a stack overflow error. However, in OCaml it should just run forever without returning.

Answer (score 0):

The let expression has syntax is `let <name> = <expr1> in <expr2>` and it defines `<name>` to be bound to `<expr1>` in `<expr2>`. The `<name>` itself is not visible in the scope of `<expr1>`, in other words it is not recursive by default. And that feature could be (and often used) to give the same names the new meaning, e.g., this is the canonical OCaml code,

```
let example () = 
  let name = "Alice" in
  let name = "Professor " ^ name in
  print_endline name
```

The same technique approach is used in the `let (-) x y = y - x in 1 - 2 - 3`, where we redefine the `(-)` in terms of the original `(-)` operator which is still seen untouched in the scope of the `y - x` expression.

However, when we add the `rec` keyword to the let definition then the name is immediately visible in the scope of the currently defined expression, e.g.,

```
let rec (-) x y = y - x
(*       ^          | *) 
(*       |          | *)
(*       +----------+ *)
```

here `-` in `x - y` refers to the currently defined function, so we have a recursive definition that says that x minus y is y minus x - a bogus definition.